# R loop through file and count differences between values in each line

Tags: r

I have a data frame with col1, val1 and val2. See the example below. 'diff_row_val1' was added only to explain the problem.

```
col1    val1     val2   diff_row_val1
1       1000     5000              NA
2       1500     5500             500
3       2000     6000             500
4       2500     6500             500
5      25000    29000           22500
6      25500    29500             500
7      26000    30000             500
8        100     4100          -25900
9        600     4600             500
```

I want to loop through the file line by line & always check if the difference between the values in column 'val1' is = 500. I've added the column 'diff_row_val1', so you could see what I mean. If this is the case he should continue until FALSE and store in the output the values from col1, val1 and a new column: total. Total contains the sum of the differences between the values in 'val1'. In the first case this is: (1500-1000)+(2000-1500)+(2500-2000)=1500

My output should look like this

```
col1    val1    total
   1    1000    1500
   5    25000   1000
   8    100      500
```

I've started with a for and a while loop, but I'm stuck at generating the output.

```
total = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  while (val1[i+1] == val1[i] + 500) {
      total += 500
      ....
  }
}
```

Comment: not understand what total is

Comment: @nurandi added extra explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**Data**

```
DF <- tribble(~col1,  ~val1,    ~val2, 
              1,       1000,     5000,         
              2,       1500,     5500,      
              3,       2000,     6000,        
              4,       2500,     6500,        
              5,      25000,    29000,          
              6,      25500,    29500,         
              7,      26000,    30000,        
              8,        100,     4100,        
              9,        600,     4600)
```

**Solution & output**

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(diff = if_else(lead(val1) - val1 == 500, 500, 0),
         group = cumsum(c(1, diff(diff) != 0))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(diff),
         n = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(n == 1 & total > 0) %>%
  select(-group, -diff, -n)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#    col1  val1  val2 total
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  1000  5000  1500
# 2     5 25000 29000  1000
# 3     8   100  4100   500
```

let me know if it works!

Comment: no this is not what I wanted. If you check the output that I provived in my question, you'll see that it should only contain 3 lines. With your solution all lines are kept.

Comment: `lead(val1) - val1` is perhaps more idiomatically expressed as `c(diff(val1), NA)`. This would also make clear that what we’re looking at here is effectively a second derivative (diff of a diff).